# JS/Angular - ngIf with map that is returned from endpoint

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, frontend

I have an endpoint that as result returns

```
HttpEntity<Map<String, Any?>>
```

What I want to do is check that map is not empty, when is not empty I want to print for example value of some key. If it's empty I want to print message something like that 'Data is not available".

This is my example method:

```
getCallsNumber(databaseId,from,to): Observable <{value: number; difference : number}>{
    return this.http.get(this.dbBaseURL + '/calls?databaseId=' + databaseId + "&from=" + from + "&to=" + to).pipe(map((res: {value: number; difference: number}) => res));
}
```

Can someone help me? `*ngIf="(calls | json) != '{}'` in div doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

You should use Angular's [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe.

```
*ngIf="(calls | async | json) != '{}'"
```